# How do I prevent Python's append method replacing existing values?

Tags: python, append

I'm trying to have user inputted numbers ordered in ascending and descending order but the append method keeps replacing the previous value and hence I only get one number in the ordering.

```
print("This is a program to order numbers in ascending and descending order.")
while 1 == 1:
    until = int(input("\nEnter how many numbers you want ordered: "))
    print("")
    loop = 0
    while loop < until:
        numbers = []
        number = float(input("Enter number: "))
        numbers.append(number)
        loop += 1
    print("\nHere are the numbers in descending order:")
    while len(numbers) > 0:
        print(max(numbers))
        largest = max(numbers)
        numbers.remove(largest)
```

Comment: declare your list numbers=[] above one level, have you tried that?

Comment: You know you haven't done enough debugging if you think the append method replaces anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you have the following line written inside a loop;

```
numbers = []
```

Every time you iterate through the loop, you will create a new variable `numbers`, hence it is overwritten on every iteration.

Try this;

```
print("This is a program to order numbers in ascending and descending order.")
while 1 == 1:
    until = int(input("\nEnter how many numbers you want ordered: "))
    print("")
    loop = 0
    numbers = []
    while loop < until:            
        number = float(input("Enter number: "))
        numbers.append(number)
        loop += 1
        print("\nHere are the numbers in descending order:")
    while len(numbers) > 0:
        print(max(numbers))
        largest = max(numbers)
        numbers.remove(largest)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the line `numbers = []` being inside your `while` loop. This resets `numbers` to an empty list on each iteration, before you append the next number.

To fix this, simply move this line outside the `while` loop as follows:

```
loop = 0
numbers = []
while loop < until:
    number = float(input("Enter number: "))
    numbers.append(number)
    loop += 1
```

Note that you also don't really need the `loop` variable in this instance. You can instead test the length of the `numbers` list directly, as follows:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < until:
    number = float(input("Enter number: "))
    numbers.append(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

*You numbers is local*

```
print("This is a program to order numbers in ascending and descending order.")
while 1 == 1:
    numbers = []
    until = int(input("\nEnter how many numbers you want ordered: "))
    print("")
    loop = 0
    while loop < until:
        #numbers = []
        number = float(input("Enter number: "))
        print(number, numbers)
        numbers.append(number)
        loop += 1
    print("\nHere are the numbers in descending order:")
    while len(numbers) > 0:
        print(max(numbers))
        largest = max(numbers)
        numbers.remove(largest)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your initial code, you state that you need the numbers in descending order, i havent provided a complete solution, but a general idea of where to head towards with what you currently have.  Just need to add some more logic depending on what the user needs, descending or ascending order. I dont know why you had the numbers.remove(largest) so i commented it out

```
    numbers = []
    print("This is a program to order numbers in ascending and descending order.")
    numbers
    while True:

        until = int(input("\nEnter how many numbers you want ordered: "))
        print("")
        loop = 0
        while loop < until:

            number = float(input("Enter number: "))
            numbers.append(number)
            loop += 1
        print("\nHere are the numbers in descending order:")
        numbers.sort()
        print(numbers)
        largest = max(numbers)
        #numbers.remove(largest)
```

as stated in my original comment "declare your list numbers=[] above one level, have you tried that?"